# How to continue tidyr/dplyr/tidyverse %>% commands to the next line?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a long command with a long line of dplyr/tidyr commands:

```
Object %>% mutate() %>% select() %>% separate() %>% separate() %>% separate %>% separate() %>% separate() %>% select()
```

and I want to separate it into multiple lines for readability sake, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Type enter after the pipe. Or are you asking something more complicated?

Comment: Yes. Generally in R you can put a line break anywhere that is **not** a valid end-of-line. Most people put line breaks after every `%>%`. As long as you don't put line breaks right before `%>%` it should be fine.

Comment: @GregorThomas I get a warning when sourcing the code `Error in fBody[[i]] : subscript out of bounds` when I try that.. let me try again tho.

Comment: @camille I get a warning when sourcing the code `Error in fBody[[i]] : subscript out of bounds` when I try that.. let me try again tho.

Comment: That seems like a different problem that we won't be able to see without a [mcve]

Comment: I will get back to this later. It only happens when I separate out by hitting return after the `%>%` does it matter that it is within a function? I will come up with an example and update @camille

Comment: ok, I had that error because separating the command was disrupting a breakpoint I set. @GregorThomas had the correct answer. thank you, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R generally continues reading more lines until it has read a complete expression. You can therefore break an expression across multiple lines by ensuring that, at the end of a given line, there’s no complete expression.

Consider

```
x = 1
+ 2
```

This code has a complete expression on its first line (`x = 1` is a valid, complete expression) so R does not continue to the next line — it evaluates the expression `x = 1`. Afterwards, `x` has the value 1.

```
x = 1 +
2
```

By contrast, this piece of code does *not* have a complete expression on its first line (`x = 1 +` would be invalid) so R continues to the next line and only then evaluates the expression `x = 1 + 2`. Afterwards, `x` has the value 3.

The same is true for the `%>%` operator. So you have multiple choices. For instance, and this is the generally recommended way, you can end lines in `%>%`:

```
Object %>%
    mutate() %>%
    select() %>%
    …
```

Conversely, some people prefer having `%>%` *at the beginning* of a line. But to make this work we need to do something to make the expression not-complete. Easy: wrap it in parentheses:

```
(Object
    %>% mutate()
    %>% select()
    %>% …
)
```

This second style is decidedly less common (and some people actively dislike it because of the redundant parentheses, which add visual clutter), but it does have its proponents.

Answer (score 2):

You can put each command on a separate line as long as it ends with the pipe, `%>%`.

```
Object %>% 
  mutate() %>% 
  select() %>% 
  separate() %>% 
  separate() %>% 
  separate() %>% 
  separate() %>% 
  separate() %>% 
  select()
```